# How to query products from pricebook

Tags: pricebook, product

I have a pricebook set up with several products in it. I would like to query these products and display them on my React app.

I am a little confused on how to go about this as I am a newbie to salesforce and only know how to query an order so far

Any leads would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SF Stack Exchange!

Since you are new I would like to point out two things about the query you've asked about.

1. This might appear confusing to you but the API Name for Product is `Product2`([link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_product2.htm)) and the one for a pricebook is `Pricebook2`([link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_pricebook2.htm)).
2. The connection between the two is established via a junction object called [PricebookEntry](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_pricebookentry.htm).

With these 2 in mind your query would be:

`[SELECT Id, Product2Id, Product2.Name FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id='12345']`

Where `12345` is your Pricebook's Id.

Essentially that will retrieve a List of `PriceBookEntry` objects.

Now you can iterate over those objects to extract the Product objects you are interested in.

```
List<PriceBookEntry> pEntries = [SELECT Id, Product2Id, Product2.Name, Product2.IsActive FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id=:pbookId];

for (PriceBookEntry pEntry: pEntries) {
    system.debug(pEntry.Product2Id);
    system.debug(pEntry.Product2.Name);
    system.debug(pEntry.Product2.IsActive);
}
```

I imagine that once you retrieve the pEntries from APEX you can iterate over them in React and pull the Product data that you need.

If you want to return a list of products from APEX instead you can change the above code to the following:

```
public static List<Product2> getProducts(Id pbookId) {
    List<PriceBookEntry> pEntries = [SELECT Id, Product2Id, Product2.Name, Product2.IsActive FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id=:pbookId];

    List<Product2> products = new List<Product2>();
    for (PriceBookEntry pEntry: pEntries) {
        Product2 aProduct = new Product2();
        aProduct.Id = pEntry.Product2Id;
        aProduct.Name = pEntry.Product2.Name;
        aProduct.IsActive = pEntry.Product2.IsActive;
        // add any additional fields from your query.
        products.add(aProduct);
    }
    return products;
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful mate :) Could you however provide some insight as to how exactly I would use [SELECT Id, Product2Id, Product2.Name FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id='12345'] when making a get request to the salesforce API? Right now I use the below to get the info about the price book

Comment: const result = await axios({
   method: 'get',
   url:
    'https://tahina-test2-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Pricebook2/01kjhhhbhbhkbk',
   data: {
    fields: 'Name'
   },
   headers: {
    Authorization:
     'Bearer 00D2X000001esWS!ASAAjbhvhvhvA4rn1'
   }
  });

Comment: @Kisho How is your request payload allowing you to identify the pricebook you need? All you are sending in is `fields: 'Name'`.

Comment: So I should request for Product2Id and Product2Id.Name?

Comment: I am now running into a cors issue :/ I did not have this issue when I whitelisted http://localhost:8000 last night. Do you know a workaround for this? @Arthlete

Comment: @Kisho I am not sure about your requirements. I imagine you need to have some information present about the pricebook before you start looking for the associated products. You might want to open a new question about the cors issue.

Comment: Hi again @Arthlete, I sorted the CORS issue. With regard to fetching the PriceBookEntry objects from PriceBook2, do you have any suggestions on how I can structure my Get query? Right now it looks like onst result = await axios({
   method: 'get',
   url:
    'https://tahina-test2-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Pricebook2/01s2X000002XyrMQAS',
   data: {
    fields: 'Name'
   },
   headers: {
    Authorization:
     'Bearer 00D2X000001esWS!ASAAQG1hpJDqk71EfwEsDjQEOIVpxLK6B86D8g3yhU5tlUWBtcHoZhpbCtu.kinCTNz03pmHu4xgE_iORJ8e01tZ'
   }
  });

Comment: @Kisho I think that the best approach for you would be to make a Rest API, in salesforce, call that and pass the pricebook id how you are doing now. Then that rest api can query and build your list of products and then return those to you.